# I need the closest smaller value in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function, select

I'm making experience points based rank system for my mmorpg. Let's say I have 2 tables,

- table1: username - exp
- table2: rankname - exp

each rank require a specific amount of exp to get promoted to. Now let's say username: Me has 550 exp, and in table2 we have:

- rank1 - 200
- rank2 - 600

now I want php function to tell me that I'm still at rank1 by checking my exp against table 2 exp although my exp is not a value in exp column. I did my best and I got:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
boolean given in... line 6
```

here's my code:

```
function expToRank($userexp)
{
   global $mysqli;
   $sql="SELECT TOP 1 *
         FROM table2
         WHERE ABS(".$userexp."-exp) =
         ( SELECT MIN( ABS(".$userexp."-exp)) from table2 )";
   $result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
   $rankarray=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   $rankname=$rankarray["rankname"];
   return $rankname;
}
```

tips: the 2 exp columns are BIGINT(60).

Comment: Error You got means You have probably syntax error in Your query. I always test complex queries in terminal or phpmyadmin before putting them in code. But in Your case there is no need for complex one as You already got answers below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the highest rank below a certain `exp` value with an `order by` query.  In MySQL, use `limit` instead of `top`:

```
select  * 
from    ranktable
where   exp < $userexp
order by
        exp desc
limit   1
```

Comment: Yeah that was very simple and right while I was seeking it the hard way, but you forgot to add (=) in exp <= $userexp to get the rank if you already have the same value of exp. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX(rank) FROM table2 WHERE $userexp >= exp";
```

Comment: Because you're probably looking for the name of the rank, but you'd like to sort by the amount of exp required to attain it

Comment: Ah yeah, fair enough.  I didn't quite click that numeric ranks were not being used, probably because it's so normal for them to be numeric.